# How to Divide/Split One Giant String | Python

Tags: python-3.x

I been searching for a solution on how to split one giant string in to multiple ones, it can be either a list or another string.

The problem:

```
x = "a, a b, ab, a b c"
```

How can I make it into:

```
y = "'a', 'a b', 'ab', 'a b c'"
```

Thanks for the help guys, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shorter:

```py
print(','.join(x.split(",")))
```

**Output**

`'a, a b, ab, a b c'`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need.

```
x = "a, a b, ab, a b c"
print(", ".join("'{}'".format(i.strip()) for i in x.split(",")))
```

**Output:**

```
'a', 'a b', 'ab', 'a b c'
```